# Where is iOS app customer reviews section in newly revamped (in Sep 2015) iTunes connect UI

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

Sorry about the obviously stupid question, but has anyone able to find where the customer reviews section been moved to in newly revamped (in Sep 2015) iTunes connect UI.

On previous iteration of the interface, there was a 'reviews' tab when you select your app in iTunes connect. But it's not there anymore.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a stupid question - 'stupid' is someone working for a company that prides itself on UI design and cannot design a website!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My apps > App Store > iOS APP > Additional Information > Reviews

[image]

Or, access directly:
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa/LCAppPage/viewCustomerReviews?adamId=(YOUR_APPID)&versionString=latest&platform=ios

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I couldn't see it there before.

Answer (score 3):

Now its under the Activity Tab -> Ratings and Reviews:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems they changed it again, this is how it shows  up now, and then a smaller pop up app store window shows up where the reviews can be seen. Under Additional Information only two items show up, View on App Store and Transfer App.
as of,
Sept 29, 2015