# Where did the App store Reviews go in the new iTunesconnect?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, review

Where did the App store Reviews go in the new iTunesconnect? Can't find them. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is iOS app customer reviews section in newly revamped (in Sep 2015) iTunes connect UI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821911/where-is-ios-app-customer-reviews-section-in-newly-revamped-in-sep-2015-itunes)

Comment: Would you please update the correct answer tick? It's currently pointing to out of date information, and it's easy to skip over the warning about this at the top. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming but instead a question about a particular (non-API) user offering of iTunesConnect (and the question and answers are now long-obsolete anyway).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## This information is out of date.

The information given here is historical and is not relevant to the current [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) site.

## Use the [Answer Below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33784897/2547229) instead.

Please refer to the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33784897/2547229), unless you have a burning curiosity about the history of Apple's iTunes Connect web site and want to know how it briefly worked some time in the past.

---

## Where it used to be found…

My apps > App Store > iOS APP > Additional Information > Reviews

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32850278/4648027

Comment: This content is no longer correct as it's moved since 2015/11/27.  It can now be found in the 'Activity' section.

Comment: Would it make sense to delete this answer as it is now out of date and misleading? Thanks!

Answer (score 62):

As on this date, the "Ratings and Reviews" can be found under the "Activity" section.